# Delphi OraOLEDB.Oracle provider

Tags: database, oracle, delphi

On a new project in Delphi, we use TADOConnection and the provider OraOLEDB.Oracle.1.

> First chance exception at $75912552. Exception class EDatabaseError
> with message 'Provider cannot be found. It may not be properly
> installed'. Process Transfert2.exe (13468)

With my new computer I don't have this provider on the list, I install the Oracle Client 12 but got the same problem. I registrer the dll OraOLEDB12.dll but same problem.

What I need to do to have this provider on the list ?

Comment: Follow the instructions at https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/install-odac-12c-121024.html

Comment: Thanks but I can connect to the Oracle database with PL/SQL Developer, I assume I have all the driver. My problem is located only in Delphi

Comment: You are wrong. PL/SQL do not use OLEDB driver. Having PL/SQL working does only mean you have some connectivity with the database engine at the network level. This doesn't mean you have OLEDB driver properly installed. OLEDB is a software layer above basic driver which implement an API defined by Microsoft and used by ADO components.

Comment: Ensure that the Oracle Client is the same architecture (i.e. 32-bit vs. 64-bit) as your Delphi environment. In case you need to install both, follow this instruction: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24104210/badimageformatexception-this-will-occur-when-running-in-64-bit-mode-with-the-32#24120100

Comment: I already have both installed in Program Files / Progam Files (x86).
I have the provider OraOLEDB.Oracle but not the OraOLEDB.Oracle.1

Comment: Yes, first ensure you use the 32-bit Oracle Client for Win32 app. IIRC OraOLEDB is not installed with all versions of the Oracle Client. You may have to download the biggest Client. And from my tests, OraOleDB was buggy and not reliable (e.g. with blobs). Try ODBC or direct OCI Client. For direct OCI client, check e.g. zeos/zdbc or our SynDBOracle unit as Open Source projects.